# multiple select option using material design lite

Tags: select, material-design-lite

I'm really curious to know if there is a way to create a multiple select option in a dropdown with material design lite, I've search everywhere and I've only been able to implement it using materializecss, need to know if its possible with material design lite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 13/05/2020. Still nothing for MDL.

Depending on what you use, [slim select](https://www.cssscript.com/multi-select-dropdown-component-javascript-slim-select/) could be useful.

I ended up re-designing to exclude the multiselect dropdown myself.